# Adding more insulation to an exterior wall

Tags: insulation

I am renovating my kitchen and after I removed the drywall, I have about 3" or so of open wall before I get to the R-15 faced insulation. If I wanted to add more insulation, would I leave the R-15 batt there and add unfaced insulation over that? Or should I leave it all alone and just accept some uninsulated gap. The reason for the extra padding/added framing is to accomodate some drain pipes and give the cabinets something to mount to.

Comment: How thick are your studs? 2x4 the only way to increase is with foam packing fiberglass reduces the R value.

Comment: The studs are 2x4 with a 2x3 padding/frame in front. The existing fiberglass batting is in the 2x4 stud, there's nothing in the 2x3 padding